# PHP performance: echo file_get_contents('...') V $file = file_get_contents('...'); echo $file

Tags: php, performance, file-get-contents

Which is faster in PHP:

`echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/file.txt');`

or

`$file = file_get_contents('http://example.com/file.txt'); echo $file;`

I am using server side includes (`require('/var/www/menu.php');`) for my menus etc but want to use this for certain things (eg on other domains)

Thanks

Comment: exactly the same, you are only creating a variable for the same resource, yo may loose .00001 second for that!

Comment: Do you plan on using the variable `$file` again? That's the real question here.

Comment: Then there's no point in worrying about the speed difference since it's negligible. The only point in creating a variable is if you were to use it again.

Comment: Did you try `readfile('http://example.com/file.txt')`?

Comment: +1 because those assh***s who down-rated this question didn't even presume that this guy is 13 yo boy (as written in profile), who most likelly will be a genious if he will develope his skills further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use this method hugely on everypage for very large files, then you would waste memory space by extra variables. so the better approach would be:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/file.txt');
```

It would be a better question to ask which function is faster file_get_contents() or fread()? Then the answer was if file is more than 1MB or 2MB then use file_get_contents() which can perform better.
You can see a benchmark here:

```
File Read Type          Average Execution Time            Type of File 
file_get_contents()        0.3730ms                          Small 
fread()                    0.1108ms                          Small 
file_get_contents()        0.012ms                           Large 
fread()                    0.019ms                           Large
```

Large file was 2.3MB and the small one was about 3.0KB.
I ran both functions against small files 100,000 times and ran it again on large file just once.

Comment: And also U can use methods like **stream_get_contents** which is low-level and have more flexability, for example an offset and charlength to read etc.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had been doing (not using variable) but wasn't sure what was better. I'll look into fread now.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the difference, if there is any, it is 100% negligible compared to making an HTTP request to fetch the content of `file.txt` in the first place. Write what you mean. If you don't need a variable, don't use one.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small test, but I am not sure wich can be faster in your case..
microtime is a nice tool to test spead in my opinion..

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
function microtime_float()
{
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}
$time_start = microtime_float();
echo "<textarea>".file_get_contents('http://in.gr')."</textarea>";
$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo  $time;


$time_start = microtime_float();
$file = file_get_contents('http://in.gr'); echo "<textarea>".$file."</textarea>";

$time_end = microtime_float();
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo  $time;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's my result: 0.600234985352, 0.350013971329 so the last one was way faster?

Comment: Hmm it's changing dramatically every time I reload it.

Comment: @duncan Because the HTTP transfer is extremely variable and makes up the monster part of the time.

Comment: I don't think that there is a big difference between the two, honestly.. :P but with microtime you can benchmark anything

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `$file` since u can use the variable for multiple operations. The time between the two is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple as the question:

1-st line - `echo file_get_contents('http://example.com/file.txt');` will be faster than the 2-nd because there is no variable initialization and in memory won't be collected a storage for that, moreover in PHP (wich is weak-typing) initializing a variable costs expensive. 
But if U intend to use the $file somewhere else, rather than echoing it just here, U just need this variable to be initialized.

Comment: The *memory* needs to be allocated regardless. You'll just save a tiny bit for variable handling overhead, which is really negligible.